# имя, за которым следует выражение, должно определять класс или пространство имен

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть код:

```
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::copy("C:/Users/", "E:/Backup/");
}
```

И есть ошибка, которую указал в шапке (жалуется на "filesystem" в 5 строке).

Вопрос: как это исправить?

Comment: Какой компилятор и какой поддерживаемый стандарт?...

Comment: `std::filesystem` доступен начиная с С++17

Comment: Вообще ide - visual studio 2022, у них свой компилятор, на сколько я знаю. Не знаю где версию посмотреть и стандарт .-.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-170

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Может кому поможет:

Путь по которому найти настройки:
Project > Properties > C/C++ > Language > C++ Language Standard

Команда, которую нужно вписать (в зависимости от того, какой компилятор вам нужен):

```
/std:c++17
/std:c++20
```

Вот и всё. Всем спасибо огромное, всех обнял!